# I am getting COM object System._COMObject on using Westwind.Utilities.ReflectionUtils

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, com, dynamic-keyword

I am getting COM object System._COMObject on using Westwind.Utilities.ReflectionUtils, how to read the value of this COMObject (access method) in ASP.Net core 2.2 (In MVC 5 using dynamic I was able to read the object methods but it is not working in ASP.Net core 2.2)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read [ask] and then edit your question to include the additional required information.

Comment: Is this helpful? [COM Object Access and dynamic in .NET Core 2.x](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Jan/22/COM-Object-Access-and-dynamic-in-NET-Core-2x)

Comment: That link basically gives the lay of the land. However, two things: 1) .NET Core 3.0 Preview 7 is supported for production by Microsoft, even though it's a preview. I'm not sure if you can use `dynamic` now, yet, but you can try, and if so, you can go ahead and run against .NET Core 3.0. 2) You can always just target .NET Framework instead. You don't have to target .NET Core to have an ASP.NET Core app, and if you're using COM, then you're Windows-only, regardless.

Comment: What methods are you using on the COM object with `ReflectionUtils`? 

If you're using COM Objects you should use the COM specific reflection methods which work differently than the native .NET accessors. So use `GetPropertyCom()` rather than `GetProperty()`. 

That said I haven't extensively used these tools in .NET Core 3.0/1, but they are used in a number of projects (like Markdown Monster's Web Browser Interop).

Please post more detailed information about what your actual problem is and what code you're using to access the COM object.